# Must the definition of the limit of a complex function be an inequality?

Tags: analysis, limits

Looking at a few books, the definition of the limit of a complex function is of the form:

**DEFINITION.** If $f :S\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an arbitrary complex function and $z_0$ is a limit point of $S$, then $limit_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=l$ if, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that

for all $z\in S,\ 0<|z-z_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(z) - l|<\epsilon$

But suppose I also include the equality relation in the definition to give:

**DEFINITION.** If $f :S\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an arbitrary complex function and $z_0$ is a limit point of $S$, then $limit_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=l$ if, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that

for all $z\in S,\ 0<|z-z_0|\leq\delta$ implies $|f(z) - l|\leq\epsilon$

Would this still give the same limit as the first definition in all cases?

Comment: Yes, and one can prove it using the usual trick that if $x \leq \delta/2$ then $x< \delta$. Perhaps you can give it a try and post your solution?

Comment: Yes, those definitions are equivalents : (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) since strict inequality implies large inequality, and the other way can be demonstrated by taking $\delta'=2\delta>\delta$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan How does one go about doing that? I've cracked my head but to no avail. I can't see how the implications follow when inequalities are involved.